# Linux: disable all USB networking (Ethernet & WiFi)

Tags: linux, networking, usb, udev

How can I disable all USB networking devices (both Ethernet and WiFi), but keep all other device types (e.g. memory stick) enabled?

Is there a common match key that could be used in `udev` rules?

What mechanism other than `udev` could be used?

Comment: This needs more context to be answerable. Do you just want to deter casual users, or are you worried about determined attackers? Bluetooth? Tethering a phone? USB to serial adapters? Do you need to keep other networking technologies working, or could you just disable networking altogether? Can you perhaps just remove all networking driver modules except for the one(s) you need to use?

Comment: The purpose is hardening a Linux computer security. The computer is located in semi-public area, where malicious attacker might get access to it. There are also other means to protect the computer, but I'd like to keep the USB ports enabled for other (or selected) device types (e.g. mouse/keyboard), just want to disable all USB networking, but keep networking enabled from built-in interfaces. Ethernet adapters and WiFi dongles would be a good start, but if all networking from add-on USB devices (incl BT etc.) can be disabled even better.

Comment: Add "allowedinterfaces eth0 eth1" row to /etc/dhcpcd.conf was the solution